# Azure function App exception error when receiving a post from a webhook

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I have the below as an entry point to an azure function app, when I open postman and send a post to this function app I'm getting this error.

[Error]   Executed 'Functions.http_trigger_from_vrli' (Failed,

The error is not remotely useful when I load this function app in local everything works, I'm able to do a post to https://localhost:7071/api/blahpost with the post data in the body. Code is executed on updateRT and all subsequent functions are completed successfully. It's just when I attempt to use azure functions app as the URL, I get a 500 and the above error. Am I doing something wrong with the route points that would cause this to 500 whenever it receives the payload? I can confirm via logger I'm getting past the if statement it is printing out the client IP address but doesn't appear to be executing the function inside the if statement. I'm debugging by cd'ing to the project in vscode then running "func start --verbose" again when I run it locally and send the post it works as expected.

here's an example of the payload

> {
> "alert_type": "RATE_BASED_WITH_GROUPS",
> "alert_name": "BlockMe",
> "search_period": "300000",
> "hit_oeprator": "GREATER_THAN",
> "messages": "[{"fields":[{"name":"msg","content":"primary credentials rejected - invalid user"},{"name":"count","content":"150"},{"name":"client_ip","content":"178.18.193.158"},{"name":"username","content":"stuff"},{"name":"status","content":"reject"}],"Count":150.0}]"
> }

also here's what I'm running at the root of my function app

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import updateRT
app = func.FunctionApp(blah=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
@app.route(route="blahpost")
def blahpost(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Invalid JSON format",
             status_code=400
        )
    alert_name = req_body.get('alert_name')
    messages = req_body.get('messages')
    if alert_name == "BlockMe":
        logging.info(req_body)
        for item in messages['fields']:
            if item['name'] == 'client_ip':
                targetIP = item['content']
                logging.info(targetIP)
                response = updateRT.main(targetIP)
                logging.info(response)
                return func.HttpResponse(response, status_code=200)
    if alert_name == "USER-Lockout-Alert":
        logging.info(req_body)
        for item in messages['fields']:
            if item['name'] == 'username':
                username = item['content']
                logging.info(username)
    return func.HttpResponse("Function executed successfully.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Live Metric's solved it for me my problem was 2 fold json output wasn't what I was expecting adding this to the for loop fixed the json problem

```
for item in messages[0]['fields']:
```

looking into live metrics I was able to see the logger I had created for the calling script was erroring out commented the createLogger() function and told main to use the logger in the function app using this.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

After those two changes everything worked as expected.